# Display the input value of a factor of 10

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```html
<div class="number">
  <input type="text" onkeyup="separateNum(this.value,this);" value="{input number}">
  <span>box: {number}</span>
</div>
```

I want when the user enters a number in the input, it is divided by 10 and displayed in a span.
For example, if the user enters the number 21, the user will immediately see the number 2 (without any further decimal value)

Comment: `span.innerHTML = Math.floor(input.value / 10);`

Comment: You need to mention if you are using a js Framework because it looks like it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function onInputChange(e) {
  const span = document.getElementById('result');
  span.innerHTML = Math.floor(e.value / 10);
}
```

```html
<div class="number">
  <input type="text" onkeyup="onInputChange(this)" value="22">
  <span id='result'>box: {number}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.trunc` to remove the decimal portion after dividing. This will also work correctly for negative numbers.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  this.nextElementSibling.textContent = 'box: ' + Math.trunc(this.value / 10);
});
```

```html
<div class="number">
  <input type="text">
  <span>box: </span>
</div>
```